# Как реализовать кнопку SOS?

Tags: java, android, android-context-menu

Нужно реализовать кнопку SOS. 
Принцип работы кнопки похож на принцип работы контекстного меню(`ContextMenu`), чтобы пользователь случайно не нажал на нее, она должна реагировать лишь на зажатие. 
`ContextMenu` по зажатию дает список, а мы хотим, чтобы всплывала кнопка.
Задача: Зажимаем кнопку - всплывает новая кнопка. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Решение с `Button.setVisibility(...)` не подойдет?

Comment: @post_zeew кнопка находится на главной странице внизу, вверху еще 4 кнопки и множество контейнеров, придется колдовать с разметкой, хотелось бы другое решение)

Comment: Тогда посмотрите, например, в сторону [PopupWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10844166).

Comment: @post_zeew, спасибо, буду пробовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. на кнопку вешаем `.setOnLongClickListener()`
   соответственно, колбэк будет вызываться к случае длительного нажатия на кнопку.
2. контекстное меню реализуется с помощью `PopupWindow`. Можно использовать его для отображения второй кнопки. И это правильное решение, если, конечно, ваша первая кнопка не в `PopupWindow`.
3. альтернатива 2. в `RelativeLayout` можно располагать одни объекты поверх других. соответственно, вторая кнопка может быть просто невидимой (`visibility = gone`), а при длинном нажатии на первую кнопку вызывать `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` но тут надо еще сделать, чтобы при тыке вне второй кнопки она исчезала. что делается добавлением вьюхи с `clickable=true` во весь экран позади второй кнопки.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую 1 метод